Java jInternalFrame dont show file(PDF)
I can open a PDF as an image in a JFrame, no problem, but I don't want to open a new Window for it; the PDF must be shown in a jInternalFrame.
I created with Netbeans a Design and will open the Document with the following code(Apache PDFBox):
public void openFile(){
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    File file = new File("/home/ritzmo/Labor_Clotten/PDF_Befunde/test.pdf");
                    PDDocument pdffile = Loader.loadPDF(file);
                    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdffile);
                    BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImage(0);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                    jInternalFrame2.setTitle("PDF G");                                     
                    jInternalFrame2.add(new JScrollPane(label));
                    jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

The jInternalFrame lies on the Main JFrame, but the PDF will not be shown.
I search on google, chatgpt over 3 hours but found no answers.
The Program start with no errors.
Anybody have an idea?
Greats Moritz

A JLabel is a JLabel. It will display on a JFrame or a JInternalFrame. 1) Don't use an empty catch block. Display a message in case the File is not found. 2) You need to either set the size or pack the internal frame before making it visible. 3) Verify that an image will show on the internal frame just by using an ImageIcon with a normal image not a rendered PDF image. If it works then you know the issue is with the PDFRenderer.

Check the Image you got. Size etc.
